# Favorites Adding Error

Tags: solspace

I finally managed to get Favorites to show on my page.

I've been testing the adding favorites function on a test page, but I keep on getting the "This form has expired. Please refresh and try again."

Here's how I currently have the Favorites set up:

```
                <!-- ADD a Favorite -->
            {if favorites:no_results}

                    {exp:favorites:form
                            {segment_3}_id="{segment_4}"
                            return="{path='favorites_inc/favorites_info_ajax/{segment_3}/{segment_4}'}"
                            error_page="{path='favorites_inc/error_ajax'}"
                        }
                         <p>Favorite this to
                            <select name="collection" class="form-control input-sm">
                                {favorites:collections}
                                    <option value="{favorites:collection}">
                                {favorites:collection}
                                    </option>
                                {/favorites:collections}
                            </select>
                                <button type="submit" class="fa fa-heart fa-lg" style="margin-top:-0.25em;"> <span style="color:#444;">add</span></button>
                    {/exp:favorites:form}
                        </p>
            {/if}

                {/exp:favorites:info}
            </div>
            {/if}
```

Currently using:
EE ver 2.8.1.
Favorites ver 4.0.4

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please strip your code example down to only the part you're having trouble with so it's easier for folks to read and understand. Also, please include the version of both the Favorites module and ExpressionEngine which you're currently running.

Comment: Are you caching your template in any way? That error is typical in EE for forms submitted with a cached `csrf_token` value. Make sure the hidden `csrf_token` field in the form is not cached and is refreshed when opening a new session (eg. when using another browser or computer).

Comment: It's also a good idea to compare your code with the Demo Templates that come with Favorites. Sometimes it can reveal what might be different and going wrong.